# JPA select List<Object> from entity order by list elements attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Im having a self reffering datamodel. Im trying to get a list of children ordered by an attribute using JPA (Hibernate). But Im having problems with the JPQL. Do you have a suggestion on how I can solve this?

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    private String bar;
    private List<Foo> elements;
}
```

**JPQL**

Demo JPQL to give you a hint of what Im trying to do

```
String jpql = "SELECT f.elements " +
              "FROM Foo f " +
              "Order By f.elements.bar";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to join the second table:

```
SELECT e FROM Foo f JOIN f.elements e ORDER BY e.bar
```

Comment: This is magnificent! Tks!

Comment: Okay, but how you suggest fix descartes product? I compelled to remove excess elements from results list and it is not normal work

Comment: Sorry, it's my fail. Your code good works